# How to wait until query is completed in BigQuery in Node.js

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large table (over 50GB).
And I'll make a new table using a query job.

The query result row is not required. I want to be able to wait until the job is completely finished.

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

async function run() {
    const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob({
        // Actually I'm going to use a complex query rather than a simple copy.
        query: 'SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable',
        destinationTable: {
            ...
        }
    });

    // I want to wait until the destination table creation is completed.
    // But getQueryResults() brings overflow.
    const [result] = await job.getQueryResults();

    // I'd like to do other things after the destination table is created.
    ...
}

run();
```

Like the code above I tried using getQueryResults but it gave JavaScript heap out of memory.

I also tried to use {maxResult:1} option for getQueryResults().
But it gave return before the destination table creation.

For Node.js BigQuery, is there any way to wait until the destination table creation is completed?

Comment: Have your tried paging through your results? See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#bigquery_browse_table-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `job.on('complete', ...)` event can help you. See: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/bigquery/job

You can do something like:

```js
const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(...);
await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  job
    .on('complete', resolve)
    .on('error', reject)
);

job.removeAllListeners();
```